# Dynamically ignore properties with JacksonJson

Tags: json, spring, jackson

I'm aware that there are multiple way to tell JacksonJson to ignore
properties during rendering but all of them are static. (JasonIgnore, MixIn classes, ..).

This is my scenario. A domain object can implement a interface called FilteredDomain to
allow it to be dynamically filtered. The interface is simple and only exposes one method
"getIgnoreProperties". (A list of properties to ignore).

I then register a Custom Serializer that binds to the FilteredDomain object. The
code looks something like:

```
private class FilteredDomainSerializer extends JsonSerializer<FilteredDomain> {

    public void serialize(FilteredDomain arg, JsonGenerator jgen,
            SerializerProvider provder) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {

        final BeanWrapper wrapper = PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(arg);

        for (PropertyDescriptor pd : wrapper.getPropertyDescriptors()) {
            final String name = pd.getName();

            if (arg.getIgnoreProperties().containsKey(name))
                continue;

            final Object value = wrapper.getPropertyValue(name);

            jgen.writeObjectField(name, value);
        }
    }
}
```

First, I really dislike that I need to use the Spring Bean wrapper to get a list of all properties and iterate through them (There must be a way to do this is jackson json).

Second, The code still dosen't work. I get the error:

org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException: Can not write a field name, expecting a value
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonGeneratorBase._reportError(JsonGeneratorBase.java:480)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8Generator.writeFieldName(Utf8Generator.java:270)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator.writeObjectField(JsonGenerator.java:1088)
    at com.rootmusic.util.SystemJsonObjectMapper$ValueObjectSerializer.serialize(SystemJsonObjectMapper.java:65)
    at com.rootmusic.util.SystemJsonObjectMapper$ValueObjectSerializer.serialize(SystemJsonObjectMapper.java:1)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.ContainerSerializers$IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(ContainerSerializers.java:304)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.ContainerSerializers$IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(ContainerSerializers.java:254)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.ContainerSerializers$AsArraySerializer.serialize(ContainerSerializers.java:142)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:287)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:212)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:23)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:280)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that you are not writing START_OBJECT / END_OBJECT around field-name/value pairs, so that should be easy to fix.

As to more dynamic filtering, you could read [this blog entry](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/02/entry_443.html) which includes standard methods. @JsonView works if you have sets of static definitions (one of which you can dynamically select on per-serialization basis), but if you want yet more dynamic system, @JsonFilter is the way to go.

Alternatively, another relatively simple way would be to first "convert" your POJO into a Map:

Map props = objectMapper.convertValue(pojo, Map.class);

(which is similar to serializing it as JSON, except that result is a Map which would render as JSON)

and then selectively trim Map, and serialize that as JSON. Or, if you prefer, you can use `JsonNode` ("tree model") as the intermediate thing to modify and then serialize.